# How to search for href ending with numbers with querySelectorAll()

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm looking to get all the elements that end with a number.
So for an example we have a `<a>` with this href.

```
href="artist.php?id=8932
```

Now I can get all of the occurences of the href with:

```
document.querySelectorAll("[href^='artist.php?id=']")
```

However that also gives me results such as

```
artist.php?id=8932#comments
```

So what I want is that I can only get the hrefs ending with a number to an array. I really wouldn't want to create the array first with all of the results and then clean the #extras and remove duplicates.

Note that I am not and will not be not using jQuery.

Comment: Well, CSS selectors aren't quite as all-powerful as you want them to be.  It's a couple more lines of code to get all the `artist.php` URLs and then apply one `.filter()` to them to eliminate the ones that don't match what you want.  And, when doing that filtering, you then have the full power of a regex to match exactly what you want.  You can even make it into a shared function that does it all for you if you want to use it from more than one place.

Comment: You might be able to do something super-complicated with XPath, bu really the solution is to get all the nodes with that href and just filter out the rest. Or even better, give the nodes that you are looking for a `class` attribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `querySelectorAll` doesn't accept regexp, there is no way to check if a `href` ends with a number using css selector. But you could simply filter all hrefs that end with numbers using `.filter` and `.match`.

```js
let links = [...document.querySelectorAll("[href^='artist.php?id=']")].filter(a => a.href.match(/\d+$/));
console.log(links);
```

```html
<a href="artist.php?id=123"></a>
<a href="artist1.php?id=123"></a>
<a href="artist.php?id=123#comment"></a>
<a href="artist.php?id=abc"></a>
<a href="artist.php?id=abc123"></a>
```

Comment: Thanks, this one seemed to do the job.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is misleading, I do the following test and everything works fine.

```
<a href="artist.php?id=1992">xxxx</a>

var v= document.querySelectorAll("[href^='artist.php?id=']")[0]
console.log(v.href);

output is :    
http://localhost:63342/artist.php?id=1992
```

Comment: The OP doesn't want to match URLs like `artist.php?id=8932#comments`

Answer (score 0):

While there isn't a way to include just those that end in a number, there is a way to filter OUT the references that end in `comments`.

Example in the fiddle.

```js
const ids = document.querySelectorAll("[href^='artist.php?id=']:not([href$=comments])");



console.log(ids);
```

```html
<a href="artist.php?id=8932#comments">
<a href="artist.php?id=007">
```